# Accept a binary string from user and check its validity in C?

Tags: c, string, input, binary

I'm trying to ask a user to enter two binary sequences and check if they are valid. here is my code.

```
char seq1[8], seq2[8];
printf("Enter 1st 8-bit sequence: ");
scanf("%8s", seq1);
getchar();
printf("\nEnter 2nd 8-bit sequence: ");
scanf("%8s", seq2);
getchar();
printf("\n");
printf("%s\n", seq1);
printf("%s\n", seq2);

if(strlen(seq1) < 8 || strlen(seq2) < 8){
    printf("Error: must enter 8-bits\n");
    exit(1);
}
for(int i = 0; seq1[i]!='\0'; i++){
    if(seq1[i]>48||seq1[i]<49){
        printf("Error: non-binary detected\n");
        exit(1);
    }

}
for(int i = 0; seq2[i]!='\0'; i++){
    if(seq2[i]>48||seq2[i]<49){
        printf("Error: non-binary detected\n");
        exit(1);
    }

}
```

When printing the strings I get the second string (seq2) added onto the end of seq1, and it always comes back as "Non-binary detected" even if it's all 1's and 0's.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsjT9.png)

Comment: thank you that works. I wonder why it wouldn't work with the ascii values

Comment: @IanClark Your condition was wrong.  You were checking for values greater than 48 OR less than 49, which is all values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code.

Let's try adding some extra information to your diagnostic messages:

```
if (strlen(seq1) < 8 || strlen(seq2) < 8) 
{
    printf("Error: must enter 8-bits; strlen(seq1) = %zu strlen(seq2) = %zu\n", strlen(seq1), strlen(seq2));
    exit(1);
}
for (int i = 0; seq1[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    if (seq1[i] > 48 || seq1[i] < 49) 
    {
        printf("Error: non-binary detected (seq1[%d] = 0x%hhX)\n", i, seq1[i]);
        exit(1);
    }

}
for (int i = 0; seq2[i] != '\0'; i++) 
{
    if (seq2[i] > 48 || seq2[i] < 49) 
    {
        printf("Error: non-binary detected (seq2[%d] = 0x%hhX)\n", i, seq2[i]);
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Right away we observe the error message: `Error: non-binary detected (seq1[0] = 0x31)`. That's odd, because 0x31 is the ASCII code for the digit 1, which should be an acceptable binary digit.  Reconsider your logic here:

```
seq1[i] > 48 || seq1[i] < 49 // In other words seq1[i] > '0' || seq1[i] < '1'
```

This statement will be true if `seq1[i]` contains a value that is greater than `'0'` or if it contains a value that is less than `'1'`. In other words, this statement will *always* be true and invoke the error handler.  The correct conditional for what you want to test for is:

```
if(seq1[i] != '0' && seq1[i] != '1')
```

Also, if you're reading a string that's 8 characters long, you need a minimum of 9 characters in your buffer to hold the null-terminator.

Also, explicitly including `!= '\0'` in a conditional is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Your check for wrong characters is wrong.

```
if(seq1[i]>48||seq1[i]<49)
```

This check is always true because every number is `>48` or `<49`. But you want to check if the value is `<48` or `>49`.

Correct would be

```
if(seq1[i]<48||seq1[i]>49)
```

or better readable as

```
if(seq1[i]<'0'||seq1[i]>'1')
```